# Concatenate value in view state string omitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am rying to pass viewstate value as concatenate string in a query but it's string is omitted.
eg.

```
conn.CountOfRecords("select count(1) from tgroup where PRODUCTITEM="+ViewState["pn"].ToString()+" and formname in('H1','H2','SM')") > 0)
```

and in

```
public int CountOfRecords(string cmdText, params string[] param)
```

when i check cmd text it's value is coming like

select count(1) from tgroup where PRODUCTITEM=123 and formname in('H1','H2','SM')

"" is missing from 123
It should be like
select count(1) from tgroup where PRODUCTITEM='123' and formname in('H1','H2','SM')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
conn.CountOfRecords("select count(1) from tgroup where PRODUCTITEM='"+ViewState["pn"].ToString()+"' and formname in('H1','H2','SM')") > 0)
```

You need to add a single quote before and after Double Quotes like

```
PRODUCTITEM='"+ViewState["pn"].ToString()+"' and formname
            ^                              ^
```